# How to get huge data response quickly by using NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to parse `JSON URL` with huge of parameters for getting huge of response. Here below I have mentioned `URL` with multiple parameters `(like:- School = A, B, C, etc).` every parameters getting huge of data's. Now the problem is I am getting response too slow. Its taking 2 minutes. Please give some ideas for quickly get huge data response.

My Sample URL :

```
http://example.com/school/schooldetailsget?time_from=2015-07-10&time_to=2015-08-10&school=A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,WX,Y,Z,&school_no=1
```

My Code:

```
// JSON data process
NSString *Values = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"URL %@",parameters];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:Values];

NSData *service_data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if (service_data) {

    NSError *error;
    jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:service_data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray *responsData = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"response"];
    NSLog(@"RESPONSE DATA %@",responsData); // here I am getting long time

}
```

Comment: How are you showing the data to the user? Using UITableView?

Comment: YES. I will store locally and load on tableview @iPP

Comment: You are getting network response too slow or you parse JSON too slow?

Comment: Network is very good only. The problem is I am getting huge of data. Its not loading quickly.@John Tracid

Comment: Did you actually MEASURE, where the time is consumed? You may be surprised by its result.

Comment: Yes. I checked by time duration. During get response getting long time, Customers cant wait for long time loading data. @HermannKlecker

Comment: Can you share some code along with the meaurement points? 

What do you currently use for the JSON deserialization?

And how much data are we talking about?

Comment: Please check above my code for JSON. I am passing multiple parametrs value for getting lost of data.@HermannKlecker

Answer (score 3):

So, you need to use a concept called pagination. ie. fetch the huge results in parts and show them to the user. This will require support from the webservice end.

Now, you decide to fetch results in parts, so in your url, have a page parameter and append 1, 2, 3 based on the page. And each page let the server return small amounts of data , say 10 results.

Further if you like to customize, you can even pass the pagesize along with the request. say page=1;pagesize=6. Acccordinly the server should pass the results.

Consider you have data of 100 records. You decide to have pagesize as 10, then you need to make 10 requests in parts to get the complete data. This will decrese the download time and improve the user experience as well.

Comment: Fisrt I need to get those all data's then I need to store into propertylist. But it's not loading quickly moreover I cant change into services bcz above one is already working on some other environment. Now what is the way of quickly load @ipp

Comment: I cant pass page size because API's not providing those functionalities. Any idea to split the params and passing method. Fo example I am passing A to Z school names (params). Can I split that and pass? Its possible? @iPP

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AFnetworking; it's a third party library works great:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: Thank you for sharring this. but I cant use third party library.@scamps

Comment: In this case I don't know other ways than use the NSURLConnection and paginating the data, editing the server side as @ipp said

Comment: No. I cant edit server side bcz already thats working some other enviroinments.@scamps. Can I split the total school name by three and pass it one by one?@scamps

Comment: Maybe you can achieve the same concept of pagination changing the time_from & time_to parameters in the url.
You can start loading the data of the current day and when it finishes you populate the tableview; than, when the user scroll to the end of the table, you load the next day data, parse it, and add that to the table..
But in this way you will have a tableview always showing at first the latest data...

Comment: Ho. its good idea. But day by day process difficult bcz I am getting 5 months data. If I pass atleast one month duration aso taking more time @scamps

Comment: It depends about how match data you receive;
You can try... :)

Comment: But I am trying offline process so I want to load all the data's into plist first!

Comment: If you want to download all data, save it to plist and after showing it; you cannot apply the concept of pagination.
But at least, you can download the data of the month (in asynchronous way) , show it (so the user can do something during the process) and immediately load the next month data...
at the end you will have all the data, and you can store it or do all the stuff you are doing now

Answer (score 0):

If API you use doesn't support pagination and you need to show data as quick as possible then simply fetch all this data and have it locally in app (file or DB) so you avoid network response waiting.

If you need to have this data actual then just request it in background and update your local data with new changes.